# Having some issues on PHP login script

Tags: php

This code below is having a problem..

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("databaseConnect.php"); // This creates $database by mysqli_connect().
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){ // checking if user has logged in
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id = '$id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($database, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

    $activated = $row[1]; // This is where I store permission for the user
    if(!($activated == 2 || $activated == 3)){ // if the user has not enough permission:
        header("Location: http://myWebsiteIndex.php");
    }

    // code for users
}else{
    header("Location: http://myWebsiteIndex.php");
}
?>
```

I have a user who has 3 for $activated, so they should be able to access.

When a user logges in to my website, it sets $_SESSION['id'] to store the id of the user.

This session variable is used to check if the user is logged in.

However, when I run the code several time, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes, it will run the '// code for users' part, and sometimes it will just redirect to my 'http://myWebsiteIndex.php'.

How would I fix this??

Comment: `if(!($activated == 2 || $activated == 2)){ `. I guess you have to replace one "2" with a "3".

Comment: with 2 and 1 i guess. anyway both part of if else statement redirects to same page as mentioned

Comment: dumb questions, but are you sure you mean $row[1] and not $row[0], and why are you checking $activated == 2 twice with an OR `||` between?

Comment: Sorry // it was typo...

Answer (score 0):

First, try changing the headers to different redirects. What part of the conditional is failing? If the `$_SESSION['id']` is not properly set it will redirect to the same url as it will redirect to when the user does not have proper permissions. Changing one of them will show you what part is executed when you encounter the behaviour.

Second, the comment from Barth is helpful. The `if(!($activated == 2 || $activated == 2))` evaluation seems incorrect. You are evalutaing for (not) 2 or 2.

Third, take note of your session data and compare when the redirect happens to when it does not.